# Checking False in torch.isfinite is created by -float("inf") only in the input tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, boolean, assert, tensor

I have a tensor `t` of `float` values which can in places include `float('-inf')` or `float('inf')`. The shape of the tensor can be pretty large.
I create a variable `mask` using [torch.isfinite](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isfinite.html) which returns a new tensor with boolean elements representing if each element is finite or not.

I want to add an `assertion` check that only `-float("inf")` is found in `t` when the `mask` value is false. How can I do it concisely without looping through the tensors?

```
t = torch.tensor(
            [[float('-inf'), 1.5, 0.5, 2.0], 
            [5.0, 3.0, float('-inf'), 5.5],
            [0.5, float('-inf'), 3.0, 2.0]]
)

mask = torch.isfinite(t)
print(mask)
>>> tensor([[False,  True,  True,  True],
          [ True,  True, False,  True],
          [ True, False,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert torch.all(t[mask==False] == float('-inf'))`